# Processing: Stop a Circle from moving when it touches a line?

Tags: java, animation, processing

I have a circle growing in radius and I want it to stop growing whenever the circle hits a line segment in my sketch. These line segments are in random locations. I just need an if statement to put before I calculate how much the circle should grow by to check whether or not it has hit a line segment. Any ideas of what the if statement would look like?

Comment: I'd start by googling something like "circle line segment intersection" and try something out first. If you get stuck you can post a [mcve] and ask a more specific question.

Comment: Figured it out! Some dude that posted before helped me out and I was going to give him best answer, but he deleted his answer for some reason. oh well.